# In Objective C, how to find out the return type of a method via reflection?

Tags: objective-c, reflection, runtime, introspection

```
@interface Foo : NSObject {
}

- (Bar)bar;
```

At runtime, given [Foo class], how do we find out the return type of all methods Foo has?

I have been studying the Objective-C runtime API for a while now; as far as I could tell, there is no way to get the return type (i.e. Class) of a method or a property.  This seems to be a serious omission in any reflection API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell basic information like what C type it is, but you can't differentiate between various instance types (or classes) on the return type.

Objective-C was never designed nor intended to have that level of a reflection.  Mostly because doing so would massively increase the size of the executables (all the metadata) and supporting full argument/return-type metadata introspection for all C types -- think C++ types -- would be incredibly complex.

Already, there have been cases where the metadata related to the parameterization of methods has measured in the orders of magnitude larger than the generated code when passing C++ objects to Objective-C methods (literally -- MBs for the metadata for a single method call).

---

An example of a relatively simple type in argument/return-type metadata form:

```
{CGRect={CGPoint=dd}{CGSize=dd}}96@0:8@16{CGRect={CGPoint=dd}{CGSize=dd}}24{CGRect={CGPoint=dd}{CGSize=dd}}56q88
```

And a particularly egregious example from the WebKit:

> ^{Document=^^?^^?i^{ContainerNode}{Weak=^{JSValue}}^{Document}^{Node}^{Node}^{RenderObject}I^{Node}^{Node}^{TreeScope}{DocumentOrderedMap={HashMap,WTF::HashTraits,WTF::HashTraits
>
> > ={HashTable,WTF::PairFirstExtractor
> >     ,WTF::PtrHash,WTF::PairHashTraits,
> >     WTF::HashTraits
> >     ,WTF::HashTraits
> >     =^{pair}iiii}}{HashCountedSet,WTF::HashTraits
> >     ={HashMap,WTF::HashTraits,WTF::HashTraits
> >     ={HashTable,WTF::PairFirstExtractor
> >     ,WTF::PtrHash,WTF::PairHashTraits,
> >     WTF::HashTraits
> >     ,WTF::HashTraits
> >     =^{pair}iiii}}}}{DocumentOrderedMap={HashMap,WTF::HashTraits,WTF::HashTraits
> >     ={HashTable,WTF::PairFirstExtractor
> >     ,WTF::PtrHash,WTF::PairHashTraits,
> >     WTF::HashTraits
> >     ,WTF::HashTraits
> >     =^{pair}iiii}}{HashCountedSet,WTF::HashTraits
> >     ={HashMap,WTF::HashTraits,WTF::HashTraits
> >     ={HashTable,WTF::PairFirstExtractor
> >     ,WTF::PtrHash,WTF::PairHashTraits,
> >     WTF::HashTraits
> >     ,WTF::HashTraits
> >     =^{pair}iiii}}}}I^^?{RefPtr=^{SecurityOrigin}}{HashSet,WTF::HashTraits
> >     ={HashTable,WTF::PtrHash,WTF::HashTraits,WTF::HashTraits
> >     =^^{MessagePort}iiii}}{HashMap,WTF::HashTraits,WTF::HashTraits
> >     ={HashTable,WTF::PairFirstExtractor
> >     ,WTF::PtrHash,WTF::PairHashTraits,
> >     WTF::HashTraits >,WTF::HashTraits
> >     =^{pair}iiii}}BB{HashMap,WTF::HashTraits,WTF::HashTraits
> >     ={HashTable,WTF::PairFirstExtractor >,WTF::IntHash,WTF::PairHashTraits,
> >     WTF::HashTraits >,WTF::HashTraits
> >     =^{pair}iiii}}B{OwnPtr,
> >     0ul>
> >     =^{Vector,0ul>}}{RefPtr=^{DatabaseThread}}Bi{OwnPtr=^{CSSStyleSelector}}BB{RefPtr=^{CSSPrimitiveValueCache}}^{Frame}{OwnPtr=^{CachedResourceLoader}}{RefPtr=^{DocumentParser}}B{KURL={String={RefPtr=^{StringImpl}}}b1b1iiiiiiiiii}{KURL={String={RefPtr=^{StringImpl}}}b1b1iiiiiiiiii}{KURL={String={RefPtr=^{StringImpl}}}b1b1iiiiiiiiii}{KURL={String={RefPtr=^{StringImpl}}}b1b1iiiiiiiiii}{KURL={String={RefPtr=^{StringImpl}}}b1b1iiiiiiiiii}{String={RefPtr=^{StringImpl}}}{String={RefPtr=^{StringImpl}}}{RefPtr=^{DocumentType}}{OwnPtr=^{DOMImplementation}}iBiB{RefPtr=^{CSSStyleSheet}}{RefPtr=^{CSSStyleSheet}}{RefPtr=^{CSSStyleSheet}}{OwnPtr,
> >     0ul>
> >     =^{Vector,0ul>}}BBBBiB{Color=IB}{RefPtr=^{Node}}{RefPtr=^{Node}}{RefPtr=^{Node}}{RefPtr=^{Element}}Q{HashSet,WTF::HashTraits
> >     ={HashTable,WTF::PtrHash,WTF::HashTraits,WTF::HashTraits
> >     =^^{NodeIterator}iiii}}{HashSet,WTF::HashTraits
> >     ={HashTable,WTF::PtrHash,WTF::HashTraits,WTF::HashTraits
> >     =^^{Range}iiii}}S{RefPtr=^{StyleSheetList}}{ListHashSet
> >     ={HashTable*,WTF::ListHashSetNode*,WTF::IdentityExtractor*>,WTF::ListHashSetNodeHashFunctions
> >     ,WTF::HashTraits*>,WTF::HashTraits*>
> >     =^^{ListHashSetNode}iiii}^{ListHashSetNode}^{ListHashSetNode}{OwnPtr
> >     =^{ListHashSetNodeAllocator}}}{ListHashSet
> >     ={HashTable*,WTF::ListHashSetNode*,WTF::IdentityExtractor*>,WTF::ListHashSetNodeHashFunctions
> >     ,WTF::HashTraits*>,WTF::HashTraits*>
> >     =^^{ListHashSetNode}iiii}^{ListHashSetNode}^{ListHashSetNode}{OwnPtr
> >     =^{ListHashSetNodeAllocator}}}{ListHashSet
> >     ={HashTable*,WTF::ListHashSetNode*,WTF::IdentityExtractor*>,WTF::ListHashSetNodeHashFunctions
> >     ,WTF::HashTraits*>,WTF::HashTraits*>
> >     =^^{ListHashSetNode}iiii}^{ListHashSetNode}^{ListHashSetNode}{OwnPtr
> >     =^{ListHashSetNodeAllocator}}}{HashMap,WebCore::FormElementKeyHash,WebCore::FormElementKeyHashTraits,WTF::HashTraits >
> >     ={HashTable
> >     ,WTF::PairFirstExtractor >
> >     ,WebCore::FormElementKeyHash,WTF::PairHashTraits >
> >     ,WebCore::FormElementKeyHashTraits>=^{pair
> >     }iiii}}{Color=IB}{Color=IB}{Color=IB}{String={RefPtr=^{StringImpl}}}{String={RefPtr=^{StringImpl}}}BBiB{Timer=^^?ddiI^{Document}{?=^q}}BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBI{StringWithDirection={String={RefPtr=^{StringImpl}}}i}{StringWithDirection={String={RefPtr=^{StringImpl}}}i}B{RefPtr=^{Element}}{OwnPtr=^{RenderArena}}^{AXObjectCache}{OwnPtr=^{DocumentMarkerController}}{Timer=^^?ddiI^{Document}{?=^q}}^{Element}B{RefPtr=^{SerializedScriptValue}}dBi{OwnPtr=^{ScriptRunner}}{OwnPtr=^{TransformSource}}{RefPtr=^{Document}}i{String={RefPtr=^{StringImpl}}}{String={RefPtr=^{StringImpl}}}B{String={RefPtr=^{StringImpl}}}^{RenderObject}{RefPtr=^{TextResourceDecoder}}i{CheckedRadioButtons={OwnPtr,
> >     WTF::HashTraits,
> >     WTF::HashTraits >
> >     =^{HashMap,WTF::HashTraits,WTF::HashTraits
> >     }}}{FixedArray=[10{CollectionCache=Q^{Element}IIi{HashMap,WTF::PtrHash,WTF::HashTraits,WTF::HashTraits*>
> >     ={HashTable,std::pair*>,WTF::PairFirstExtractor*>
> >     ,WTF::PtrHash,WTF::PairHashTraits,
> >     WTF::HashTraits*>
> >     ,WTF::HashTraits
> >     =^{pair*>}iiii}}{HashMap,WTF::PtrHash,WTF::HashTraits,WTF::HashTraits*>
> >     ={HashTable,std::pair*>,WTF::PairFirstExtractor*>
> >     ,WTF::PtrHash,WTF::PairHashTraits,
> >     WTF::HashTraits*>
> >     ,WTF::HashTraits
> >     =^{pair*>}iiii}}BB}]}{FixedArray,
> >     WTF::HashTraits,
> >     WTF::HashTraits
> >     ,2ul>=[2{HashMap,WTF::HashTraits,WTF::HashTraits
> >     ={HashTable,WTF::PairFirstExtractor
> >     ,WTF::PtrHash,WTF::PairHashTraits,
> >     WTF::HashTraits
> >     ,WTF::HashTraits
> >     =^{pair}iiii}}]}{RefPtr=^{XPathEvaluator}}{OwnPtr=^{SVGDocumentExtensions}}{Vector=Q{VectorBuffer=^{DashboardRegionValue}Q}}BB{HashMap,WTF::StringHash,WTF::HashTraits,WTF::HashTraits
> >
> > > ={HashTable
> > >       ,WTF::PairFirstExtractor >
> > >       ,WTF::StringHash,WTF::PairHashTraits,
> > >       WTF::HashTraits >
> > >       ,WTF::HashTraits
> > >       =^{pair
> > >       }iiii}}BB[1{IconURL=i{KURL={String={RefPtr=^{StringImpl}}}b1b1iiiiiiiiii}}]{HashSet,WTF::HashTraits
> > >       ={HashTable,WTF::PtrHash,WTF::HashTraits,WTF::HashTraits
> > >       =^^{Element}iiii}}{HashSet,WTF::HashTraits
> > >       ={HashTable,WTF::PtrHash,WTF::HashTraits,WTF::HashTraits
> > >       =^^{Element}iiii}}{HashSet,WTF::HashTraits
> > >       ={HashTable,WTF::PtrHash,WTF::HashTraits,WTF::HashTraits
> > >       =^^{Element}iiii}}{HashMap,WTF::HashTraits
> > >       ={HashTable,WTF::PairFirstExtractor
> > >       ,WTF::CaseFoldingHash,WTF::PairHashTraits,
> > >       WTF::HashTraits >,WTF::HashTraits
> > >       =^{pair}iiii}}BBBBBBB{RefPtr=^{EventQueue}}{RefPtr=^{DocumentWeakReference}}{HashSet,WTF::HashTraits
> > >       ={HashTable,WTF::PtrHash,WTF::HashTraits,WTF::HashTraits
> > >       =^^{MediaCanStartListener}iiii}}{QualifiedName=^{QualifiedNameImpl}}B{RefPtr=^{Element}}^{RenderFullScreen}{Timer=^^?ddiI^{Document}{?=^q}}{Deque,0ul>=QQ{VectorBuffer,0ul>=^{RefPtr}Q}}B{IntRect={IntPoint=ii}{IntSize=ii}}{RefPtr=^{RenderStyle}}i{Timer=^^?ddiI^{Document}{?=^q}}{ViewportArguments=fffffff}BB{DocumentTiming=ddddd}{RefPtr=^{MediaQueryMatcher}}BII{RefPtr=^{ContentSecurityPolicy}}}16@0:8

Comment: Sure -- pass any kind of an STL conglomeration to a method as an argument.  The compiler will generate a potentially HUGE string to describe the structure that results from whatever cross-product of types that defines the argument

Comment: bbum - I really enjoyed reading your response; thank you.  You said earlier, "Objective-C was never designed nor intended to have that level of a reflection."  How did you know about this?

Comment: I've worked with Objective-C since 1988, have chatted w/Brad Cox over email, and have worked with many of the people who "owned" the language at one point in time or another.  There is some more historical information in this SO question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833756/does-objective-c-have-a-standard-library)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the Objective-C runtime functions:

```
Method class_getClassMethod(Class aClass, SEL aSelector)
void method_getReturnType(Method method, char *dst, size_t dst_len)
```

[Objective-C Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html)

First of all, get the method object, using `class_getClassMethod`

```
Method m = class_getClassMethod( [ SomeClass class ], @selector( someMethod ) );
```

Then, asks for the return type using `method_getReturnType`:

```
char ret[ 256 ];
method_getReturnType( m, ret, 256 );
NSLog( @"Return type: %s", ret );
```

Comment: Yup -- nice example.   The issue, though, is dealing with all of the edge cases and potential complexity of the type encodings.