# getting return value type of an instance method in runtime

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-runtime

I want get the return value class of an instance in runtime. The thing it's that I have a `SEL` type var where I store a selector. I have a variable named `id _instance` that points to an instance that I know it performs the selector. Before perform the method I want to know if I have to do:

```
NSObject* returnValue=[_instance performSelector:_selector withObject:params.params];
```

or:

```
[_instance performSelector:_selector withObject:params.params];
```

I have read a [post where someone explain the way to have that with objective-c runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447559/in-objective-c-how-to-find-out-the-return-type-of-a-method-via-reflection):

```
Method m = class_getClassMethod([_instance class], _selector);

char ret[256];
method_getReturnType(m, ret, 256);
NSLog(@"Return type: %s", ret);
```

But the outputs is nothing like ret is empty.

Really it can be enough to know if it's a void or have a return type but I don't know where to search. I have read the [objective-c runtime reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) but the only thing I found is the `method_getReturnType...`. Any idea?

Comment: You really don't want to be using this kind of introspection for anything but educational experiments.  Down this path lies madness and many maintenance nightmares.

Comment: Thanks for the advertisement! If you have a better suggestion on how to do it i'm open to it ;)

Comment: What are you trying to do?  I.e. why do you need to know this?   Likely worthy of a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for an instance method, you need to use `class_getInstanceMethod` rather than `class_getClassMethod`. Class methods and instance methods are obviously different things.

Answer (score 0):

After searching a while I found the library that uses Spotify for this kind of stuff, the name is MAObjcRuntime and you can found it [here](https://github.com/mikeash/MAObjCRuntime/downloads)