# Objective-C functions vs. Python modules?

Tags: python, objective-c

Just another newbie question I'm afraid. I am doing a course on python on udacity and pretty much straight away have been shown modules, such as time, and webbrowser, which make it very easy to do such tasks as time delay, opening webbrower, etc.

Is there anything so straightforward and easy to use as this in Objective-C, or what would be the equivalent to the python modules? Is it just the case that you need to write a lot more code in Objective-C alongside their provided library functions to achieve the same thing as a Python module would provide you with?

It just seems like Python modules have more im-built code with less for developer to write in code?

Comment: In Objective-C (and other C languages) you use the `#include` [(or `#import`)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439662/what-is-the-difference-between-import-and-include-in-objective-c) statement to access functions (and other things) from a library, which is roughly analogous to Python's "modules"

Comment: but do they have such easy to use functions? I have edited my question and title to make it clearer.

Comment: They have access to the [C standard library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833756/does-objective-c-have-a-standard-library) if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Python is different to most other languages with it's massive standard library, and very good module system. You might have to install third party libraries to do some tasks you could do with the standard library in Python.

Comment: That is more like what I was wondering. Sorry, I asked a specific question re obj-c equivalent to python module in title, and then in body expanded on that. Edited question, sorry Cyber for not being clear enough from the beginning.

Comment: @sweeneyrod, python fanatic detected, aha. You are not right. Standard library for ios more extensive. It has many things from image filters to database access.